# Getting a typed ArrayList from a JSON String in Java

Tags: java, json

I convert an `ArrayList` into an `JSON String` and save it into a `File`. This works perfectly. But if I try do this in reverse, my application doesn't run (I get something like a `ClassCastException`)

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
new FileReader("/sdcard/file.json"));

myArrayList = gson.fromJson(br, ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: do you have more info about that exception?

Comment: The GSON documentation contains examples that show [how to serialize and deserialize collections](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples).

Comment: can you plz provide the content of file.json...

Comment: to avoid the exception u need to hav JsonArray inside the file like [{"key" : "value"}]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) that executes and that demonstrates exactly how to get back a typed `ArrayList`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    List<Integer> outList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    outList.add(1);
    outList.add(2);
    outList.add(3);

    String json = gson.toJson(outList);

    // This is how you tell gson about the generic type you want to get back:
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>(){}.getType();
    ArrayList<Integer> inList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    for (int i : inList) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

The fact that this code doesn't explode proves that the `ArrayList` is in fact typed correctly.

I went to/from String *not* via a file to simplify the example down to the bare minimum.

Comment: Actually to keep the example as simple as possible you could just use a string i.e. `String json = "[ 1, 2, 3 ]";`

Comment: No - that would presuppose what json is created by gson. This code will work even if gson changes its implementaiton

Comment: JSON is a standard ([www.json.org](http://www.json.org)).  If GSON does not work with correct JSON, then it is a bug.  That somebody who has 17.2k rep does not understand something so fundamental is truly worrying.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples), you don't supply `ArrayList.class` as parameter you specify the type the list contains by using a `TypeToken` and passing that to `fromJSON`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType(); //change this to whatever type you json contains
Collection<Integer> ints2 = gson.fromJson(br, collectionType);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Submission> submitArray = Array.asList(gson.fromJson(submitJson, (new Submission[]{}).getClass()));
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create the ArrayList from the native array. 
Do you realy need an ArrayList or just an implementation of the List interface?